# cannot access javascript file even the path is correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, filepath

It seems to be a common problem with Nodejs, and i tried all the solution without success.
My require('filepath') request fail, with the error " ENOENT: no such file or directory, open "a filepath"
For example i have those folders:

[image]

i want to use action1.js and data.json into folder2 action2.js

So while require with relative path don't work (why ?):

```
const action1 = require('../folder1/action1.js')
const data = require('../../data/data.json')
```

I tried absolute path, but that do not worked too

```
const action1 = require(path.join( __dirname,'../folder1/action1.js'))
const data = require(path.join( __dirname,'../../data/data.json'))
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: hey, your quotes are invalid. you are aware of that? require('../folder1/action1.js') etc...

Comment: Yep sorry this is a typing error, it was correctly written in my local code. Thank you for the correction

Comment: Looks fine... I assume the code you posted is within `action2.js`? Can you post the actual error instead of stuff like `a filepath` etc

Comment: There's no issue with the code you've posted. So either your directory structure isn't what you expect, or there are file name capitalization differences. Are you sure the error you're getting is from the require lines you've showed us?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct, but I suggest you check the scope of your directory.

You can try the following steps to see your directory structure from action2.js

`npm install directory-tree`

Inside your file add the following lines:

```
const dirTree = require("directory-tree");

const tree1 = dirTree('../');
console.log(tree1);

const tree2 = dirTree('../../');
console.log(tree2);
```

This might help you find the scope of your directory. It's not a solution, but a way of helping you debug.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have found my problem. And it was coming from an other require on an other file. My code here was correct.

Sorry for the dumb question, be indulgent i'm noob, and thank you for the answer.